# How to get all adjacent combinations of a string in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, combinations, permutation

Say you had a list like:

```
['hi', 'my_name', 'is_max', 'arnold']
```

How would you generate all adjacent combinations joined with a '_' i.e

```
[['hi_my_name_is_max_arnold'], ['hi', 'my_name_is_max_arnold'], ['hi_my_name_is_max', 'arnold'], ['hi', 'my_name_is_max', 'arnold' ... etc
```

Notice its only adjacent combinations of any length i. you couldn't have `'my_name_hi'`.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, use `itertools.product`

```
from itertools import product

l = ['hi', 'my_name', 'is_max', 'arnold']
sep = [("_", ";") for _ in range(len(l)-1)]
t = "{}".join(l)
res = [t.format(*s).split(";") for s in product(*sep)]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[['hi_my_name_is_max_arnold'],
 ['hi_my_name_is_max', 'arnold'],
 ['hi_my_name', 'is_max_arnold'],
 ['hi_my_name', 'is_max', 'arnold'],
 ['hi', 'my_name_is_max_arnold'],
 ['hi', 'my_name_is_max', 'arnold'],
 ['hi', 'my_name', 'is_max_arnold'],
 ['hi', 'my_name', 'is_max', 'arnold']]
```

Explanation:

The solution is basically to generate a *joiner* `_`, and a *separator* `;`. For each space between the words, one can either put the joiner or the separator.

That being said, all possible outcomes can be calculated using the triple product of `("_", ";")`, since there exists three spaces and two possible inputs:

```
product(("_", ";"), ("_", ";"), ("_", ";"))
# or equivalent of product(*sep)
```

which should yield 8 products:

```
[('_', '_', '_'),
 ('_', '_', ';'),
 ('_', ';', '_'),
 ('_', ';', ';'),
 (';', '_', '_'),
 (';', '_', ';'),
 (';', ';', '_'),
 (';', ';', ';')]
```

The next problem then becomes how to put them between the words. I've used `str.format` to concatenate the words:

```
t = "{}".join(l)
t
# 'hi{}my_name{}is_max{}arnold'
```

One can now freely put the triplets from `product(...)` into the joined words and make output:

```
[t.format(*s) for s in product(*sep)]
# Outcome:
['hi_my_name_is_max_arnold',
 'hi_my_name_is_max;arnold',
 'hi_my_name;is_max_arnold',
 'hi_my_name;is_max;arnold',
 'hi;my_name_is_max_arnold',
 'hi;my_name_is_max;arnold',
 'hi;my_name;is_max_arnold',
 'hi;my_name;is_max;arnold']
```

and then use `str.split`, or in my case, do it in one line:

```
[t.format(*s).split(";") for s in product(*sep)]
```

Output:

```
[['hi_my_name_is_max_arnold'],
 ['hi_my_name_is_max', 'arnold'],
 ['hi_my_name', 'is_max_arnold'],
 ['hi_my_name', 'is_max', 'arnold'],
 ['hi', 'my_name_is_max_arnold'],
 ['hi', 'my_name_is_max', 'arnold'],
 ['hi', 'my_name', 'is_max_arnold'],
 ['hi', 'my_name', 'is_max', 'arnold']]
```

Comment: The output is exactly what I am looking for +1

Comment: @OultimoCoder I've added some explanation. Let me know if anything unclear ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through the list from the first element thru to the last element. As you iterate thru them, concatenate using string join function.

```
a = ['hi', 'my_name', 'is_max', 'arnold']
b = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(a)+1):
        b.append('_'.join(a[i:j]))
for i in b: print(i)
```

Output:

```
hi
hi_my_name
hi_my_name_is_max
hi_my_name_is_max_arnold
my_name
my_name_is_max
my_name_is_max_arnold
is_max
is_max_arnold
arnold
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do the below:-

```
txt=['hi', 'my_name', 'is_max', 'arnold']
txtg=""
newlist=[]
for i in range(0,len(txt)):
    for j in range(i,len(txt)):
        if txtg=="":
            txtg=txt[j]
        else:
            txtg=txtg+"_"+txt[j]
        newlist.append(txtg)
    txtg=""

print(newlist)
```

Output:

```
['hi', 'hi_my_name', 'hi_my_name_is_max', 'hi_my_name_is_max_arnold', 'my_name', 'my_name_is_max', 'my_name_is_max_arnold', 'is_max', 'is_max_arnold', 'arnold']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
data = ['hi', 'my_name', 'is_max', 'arnold']
def groups(d, c = []):
  if not d:
     yield c
  else:
    if c:
       yield from groups(d[1:], c = c[:-1]+[f'{c[-1]}_{d[0]}'])
    yield from groups(d[1:], c + [d[0]])


print(list(groups(data)))
```

Output:

```
[['hi_my_name_is_max_arnold'], ['hi_my_name_is_max', 'arnold'], ['hi_my_name', 'is_max_arnold'], ['hi_my_name', 'is_max', 'arnold'], ['hi', 'my_name_is_max_arnold'], ['hi', 'my_name_is_max', 'arnold'], ['hi', 'my_name', 'is_max_arnold'], ['hi', 'my_name', 'is_max', 'arnold']]
```